# Container Is Not Responding With Position Relative

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a page with a few cards that flip on hover and it works fine for the most part, the problem I'm having is, when the page shrinks and the cards stack, the cards on the bottom aren't moving down the page.

I have the container set to Position Relative but the back side is Position Absolute.

```css
.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
}
.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
}
.flipper {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
.front,
.back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
@import 'card-img';
 .front {
  z-index: 2;
  span {
    display: none;
  }
}
.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  margin-top: 11px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #434343;
  color: $off-white;
  h4 {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .game-title {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .date {
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .game-info {
    display: table;
    min-height: 245px;
    p {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: justify;
      font-size: 1.1em;
    }
  }
}
.btn-preorder {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">

  <div class="flip-wrap">
    <div class="flip-container">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front front-1"><span>Game Title Here</span>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <h4 class="game-title">Star Wars: Battlefront</h4>
          <div class="date">
            Release Date:
            <p>November 20<sup>th</sup> 2015</p>
          </div>
          <div class="game-info">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident ducimus omnis modi ipsum ex commodi eum! Cupiditate, id, pariatur. Repellendus, id, incidunt. Labore ea, blanditiis, officia pariatur exercitationem earum autem. Lorem ipsum
              dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae animi, laboriosam cum rem fugit, quis, et sed, laudantium ipsa reprehenderit aut unde ad tempora expedita libero dolor est repellat. Unde. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
              elit. Dolorem enim quam autem sunt ipsam tempora rem eum illo soluta odio in blanditiis quis repellat sequi, nihil ad laborum, totam consequuntur.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="btn btn-primary btn-preorder">Pre-order</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- End col -->
```

Comment: Anyone? Or if there's a better way to handle/position the flip animation that I could use

Answer (score 0):

It's because `.back` exceeding more than `width: 100%;` . you can override with adding `box-sizing: border-box;`

**Like this**

```
.front, .back {
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
     backface-visibility: hidden;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Here is the working demo**

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.flip-container {
     -webkit-perspective: 1000;
     -moz-perspective: 1000;
     -o-perspective: 1000;
     perspective: 1000;
}
 .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
     -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
 .flip-container, .front, .back {
     width: 100%;
     min-height: 400px;
}
 .flipper {
     -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
     -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
     position: relative;
}
 .front, .back {
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
     backface-visibility: hidden;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .front {
     z-index: 2;
}
 span {
     display: none;
}
 .back {
     -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
     margin-top: 11px;
     padding: 10px;
     border: 3px solid #434343;
     color: $off-white;
}
 h4 {
     margin: 0;
}
 .game-title {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     font-weight: 700;
}
 .date {
     font-weight: 700;
}
 .game-info {
     display: table;
     min-height: 245px;
}
 p {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: justify;
     font-size: 1.1em;
}
 .btn-preorder {
     position: relative;
     margin-left: 5%;
     margin-top: 10px;
     width: 90%;
}
 body {
     margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <div class="flip-wrap">
        <div class="flip-container">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="front front-1"><span>Game Title Here</span> </div>
                <div class="back">
                    <h4 class="game-title">Star Wars: Battlefront</h4>
                    <div class="date"> Release Date:
                        <p>November 20<sup>th</sup> 2015</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="game-info">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident ducimus omnis modi ipsum ex commodi eum! Cupiditate, id, pariatur. Repellendus, id, incidunt. Labore ea, blanditiis, officia pariatur exercitationem earum autem. Lorem ipsum
                            dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae animi, laboriosam cum rem fugit, quis, et sed, laudantium ipsa reprehenderit aut unde ad tempora expedita libero dolor est repellat. Unde. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
                            elit. Dolorem enim quam autem sunt ipsam tempora rem eum illo soluta odio in blanditiis quis repellat sequi, nihil ad laborum, totam consequuntur.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn btn-primary btn-preorder">Pre-order</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End col -->
```